# Function to display circular double ended queue

Tags: c++

I tried to display circular double ended queue. the problem comes when I insert an element at front when my pointer is at 0th position it goes to (SIZE - 1)th position where size is maximum defined number. I cannot apply for loop for it so I used if else condition ass given in my code below:`

```
void display(struct Q*q)
{
    int i ;
    if(q->front <= q->rear)
    {   
        for(i = q->front; i<= q->rear; i= (i+1)%size)
        cout<<q->data[i]<<" ";
    }
    else
    {

        for(i = q->front; i<= size; i++)
            cout<<q->data[i]<<" ";
        i=0;
        for(i = 0; i<= q->rear;i++)
            cout<<q->data[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

output:

```
10 9 10
```

the 9 is decremented every time I insert 10 in front of the queue
for ex:

```
10 10 8 10
10 10 10 7 10
```

and so on. How to remove that counter in this function? i just want my output to be :

```
10 10 10 10
```

**EDIT**

OP added the following information in a comment:

```
struct Q 
{ 
    int data[size]; 
    int front = -1; 
    int rear = -1; 
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `struct Q`?

Comment: *"How to remove that counter in this program"* - in *what* program? I see a function with some unknown structures in use. Update with a mcve, preferably after stepping through your code in a *debugger* in effort to root out your suspicion of problem(s).

Comment: The `display` function can probably be implemented with a single loop but there is so much code missing that writing an answer would involve a lot of guessing. Also you write a lot about "insert" but there is no insert code posted here.

Comment: OT: `i<= size;` ==> `i < size;` I guess

Comment: How do you know if the queue is empty? when front is equal to rear? Or?

Comment: @4386427 thanks man!

Comment: @4386427 initially I set front = -1 and rear = -1, so that queue is empty.

Comment: @scohe001    `  struct Q
{
 int data[size];
 int front = -1;
 int rear = -1;
 
}; `

Answer (score 0):

With the information given by OP in comments, it seems that `-1` is used to mark the queue as empty.

So the display function can be written like:

```
void display(struct Q*q)
{
    if(q->front < 0 || q->rear < 0)
    {
        cout << "Queue empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Check that front and rear are in valid range
    assert(q->front < size);
    assert(q->rear < size);

    int tmp = q->front;
    while(tmp != q->rear)
    {   
        cout << q->data[tmp] << " ";
        tmp = (tmp + 1) % size;
    }
    cout << q->data[tmp] << " ";
}
```

**p.s.** The question still provides too little information to answer the part about the changing data value